# Adding an action to event handler arguments c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, event-handling

I have a problem with some code I need to refactor. Right now it uses lambdas as event handlers, but they are not removed properly. From what I have read, this is not even possible?  Anyway I would like to rewrite it to use a delegate instead of an anonymous function, and now my problem is that right now it takes an action as parameter, and I can't seem to figure out how to pass the action on to my new delegate. This is the code:

```
void RetrieveData(
            int pointId,
            int? chartCollectionId,
            Action action)
        {
            if (pointId <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("PointId not valid");

            LastPointId = NextPointId;
            NextPointId = pointId;

            Clear();

            _csr = new CustomerServiceRepository();

            _csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted += (se, ea) =>
                                                            {
                                                                _cachedCharts = ea.Result;
                                                                ChartDataRetrieved(ea.Result);
                                                                if (action != null)
                                                                    action.Invoke();
                                                                _csr = null;
                                                            };
            _csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataAsync(
                Settings.Current.Customer.CustomerName,
                pointId,
                chartCollectionId);

            _csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted -= (se, ea) => //remove after usage
                                                            {
                                                                _cachedCharts = ea.Result;
                                                                ChartDataRetrieved(ea.Result);
                                                                if (action != null)
                                                                    action.Invoke();
                                                                _csr = null;
                                                            };
        }
```

I was thinking that maybe I could create the following:

```
public class extendedEventArgs : GetChartDataCompletedEventArgs
        {
            Action foo { get; set; }
        }

        void tang(object sender, extendedEventArgs e)
        {
            _cachedCharts = e.Result;
            ChartDataRetrieved(e.Result);
            if (action != null)
                action.Invoke();
            _csr = null;
        }
```

And the pass the action as a parameter in the extended event args, but when I try to use it like this

```
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted += new EventHandler<extendedEventHandler>(tang);
```

It gives an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type  System.EventHandler<Conwx.Net.Client.CustomerClient.Controls.ChartControls.ChartListForecast.extendedEventArgs>'  to  System.EventHandler<Conwx.Net.Client.Framework.CustomerServiceReference.GetChartDataCompletedEventArgs>'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Alternative solutions are also welcome.

.K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read it, the key problem here is not being able to remove the handler; if so, all you need it to store the delegate (where in the below, `YourDelegateType` is meant to mean: the defined type of `GetChartDataCompleted`):

```
YourDelegateType handler = (se, ea) =>
    {
        _cachedCharts = ea.Result;
        ChartDataRetrieved(ea.Result);
        if (action != null)
            action.Invoke();
        _csr = null;
    };
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted += handler;
...
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted -= handler;
```

You can also make it self-unsubscribing (i.e. so that it unsubscribes when the event is raised):

```
YourDelegateType handler = null;
handler = (se, ea) =>
    {
        _cachedCharts = ea.Result;
        ChartDataRetrieved(ea.Result);
        if (action != null)
            action.Invoke();
        _csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted -= handler;
        _csr = null;
    };
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted += handler;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this because it's the class which *raises* the `GetChartDataCompleted` event which creates the object passed (as a reference) to the event handler. It will be creating a `GetChartDataCompletedEventArgs` - not an `extendedEventArgs`.

If you think about it, it's like trying to implement an interface which looks like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(object x);
}
```

with a class like this:

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
    // We don't care if someone calling IFoo wants to pass us something
    // other than a string - we want a string, darn it!
    public void Foo(string y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y.Length);
    }
}
```

That's clearly not going to work...

Marc has shown one approach to fixing it - but I'd also point out that you should probably *actually* only be removing the delegate *when the event fires*. I'm assuming that the fact that the method is called `GetChartDataAsync` means it's a non-blocking method... so unsubscribing from the event immediately after calling it probably isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer to avoid the anonymous methods, you can manually do essentially what the compiler is doing for you under the hood. That is, create a closure class to hold the Action and a reference to itself as fields and which exposes the method you want to assign to the event. Something like this:

```
class RetrieveDataClosure
{
   private Action action;
   private MyClass self;

   public RetrieveDataClosure(Action action, MyClass self)
   {
      this.action = action;
      this.self = self;
   }

   public void ChartDataCompleted(object se, MyEventArgs ea)
   {
      self._cachedCharts = ea.Result; 
      self.ChartDataRetrieved(ea.Result); 
      if (action != null) 
         action.Invoke(); 
      self._csr = null; 
   }
}
```

Which you'd use in your code like this:

```
var closure = new RetrieveDataClosure(action, this);
_csr = new CustomerServiceRepository();
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted += closure.ChartDataCompleted;
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataAsync( 
   Settings.Current.Customer.CustomerName, 
   pointId, 
   chartCollectionId); 
_csr.ServiceClient.GetChartDataCompleted -= closure.ChartDataCompleted;
```